# Linux Customized Cron - Run a cron from Mysql

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a web server running multiple vhosts and each vhost has a lot of jobs that need to run that are both web requests and ruby.

For example, I have to run a ruby script every 2 min to check email, 
then another ruby script once an hour to check for updates.
then I need to run a webpage at 6 pm every night to send me an email report.
then I need to run another webpage every 6 hours for general tasks.

So how i currently do it is in crontab and i enter a new line for each entry
for the ruby scripts i just call the rb file and for webpages i run wget and it does work perfectly

the problem is that im now starting to get alot of entries 100+ in my crontab
i if i write a new script i have to fo add the entry for each vhost in crontab (And problems happen when i miss one)

What i was hoping to build a cron in mysql then for each virtual hosts call the "mysql cron" once then it will add the rest.

Then i only need one entry in crontab, and iff i need to add a new schedule in  i just have to write an entry into mysql

Does anyone have any idea how i could do this

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use MySQL scheduled jobs (aka events) for scripts exclusively dedicated for database?

I think it could be the better way to go. Separate your scripts in two categories: database and others. Others will continue be ran on the linux cron (or windows schedule), and, database scripts would be ran on MySQL Events.

Advantages to be considered:

- Organization
- Security (no more mysql passwords walking along o/s)
- Backups (when you issue an backup of your database, scripts will be too --events)

  [Click here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) for see how to create MySQL events.

  A small sample of event is provided below. The idea is to trigger a update every 6 hours:

  `CREATE EVENT my_first_event ON SCHEDULE EVERY 6 HOUR DO BEGIN UPDATE tab_pricelist SET promo_price = full_price - (full_price * discount) END ;`